# Can I screw up forever?

Tags: neptunia-v

One of the less pleasant features of Hyperdimension Neptunia 1 and Mk2 (though less so in 2) is that if you take too many of the "wrong" quests, shares will be distrubuted in such a way that makes it hard or even impossible to get the best ending in a given playthrough.

Is it still possible to mess up quests/shares/whatever so bad that I'm unable to get a certain ending? I don't need to know what the endings are/any spoilers, I just want to know how free I am in taking quests, or if I should avoid quests like the plague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question more thoroughly in this game completing quests and raising your shares only changes the stats of the CPUs related to that nation. Different endings are based upon either doing ALL the quests/shares, new game + quests, Or some special bosses later in the game. All in all do quests and gain shares to make your favorite nations CPUs stronger

Answer (score 0):

No. They practically tell you to do the quests in so many ways. It falls into your rating at the end of every chapter.

Comment: So the shares are no longer relevant for story progression/endings or what?